# How to pass a pointer to a list of handles to the UpdateProcThreadAttribute function

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl, kernel32

I have an application that spawns multiple **CreateProcess** threads and I'm successfully redirecting the stdout and stderr output to text files for each one.

However, I've discovered the feature whereby the stdout/strderr handles are inherited by all such threads and not just the ones I want them to be inherited by. So I've embarked on a journey to use the **InitializeProcThreadAttributeList**, **UpdateProcThreadAttribute** functions and **EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT** and a **STARTUPINFOEX**  structure in the **CreateProcess** function to get around this but I'm stuck.

If I use **PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST** as the **Attribute** argument in **UpdateProcThreadAttribute** procedure it expects *the lpValue parameter to be a pointer to a list of handles to be inherited by the child process*.

For the List I've tried using a

```
TList<Cardinal>
```

and also creating an array of Cardinals but couldn't get either approaches to compile!

Question: How do I create and populate such a list?

Secondly, [in this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1054558/how-to-auto-attach-a-process-in-Delphi) it is using the functions and procedures from kernel32.dll but they also exist in the Windows unit too (I'm using Delphi 10.3) although the definitions differ:

For example, `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList( nil, 1, 0, vAListSize );` won't compile using the Windows unit due to the nil argument because *Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical* but I have no such issue using the one in kernel32

Question: Which version of these functions/procedures should I be using?

Thanks.

Comment: you need pass pointer to array ( `HANDLE h[n]` ) of handles

Comment: Why would you think to use `Cardinal` when the function expects `THandle`? If you can't pass `nil` to `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` then I suspect that you should just declare `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` yourself, and get it right. That's what I do FWIW

Comment: Good question! I probably arrived there because the definition says "pValue - System.Cardinal" and I've been trying all sorts to get the thing working but to no avail! And using @vMyHandles in UpdateProcThreadAttribute where vMyHandles is an array of handles doesn't compile. I'm somewhat confused about using pointers

Comment: Don't use the IDE as your reference for the Windows API. Use the actual Windows API reference. And don't trust Emba header translations. They are often wrong.

Comment: `@vMyHandles` is a pointer to the address of the array. That's one level of indirection too far. Anyway, you have all you need from my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case it is useful, here's my code to implement all of this:

```
function InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
  lpAttributeList: Pointer;
  dwAttributeCount: DWORD;
  dwFlags: DWORD;
  var lpSize: SIZE_T
): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32;

function UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
  lpAttributeList: Pointer;
  dwFlags: DWORD;
  Attribute: DWORD_PTR;
  lpValue: Pointer;
  cbSize: SIZE_T;
  lpPreviousValue: PPointer;
  lpReturnSize: PSIZE_T
): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32;

function DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(
  lpAttributeList: Pointer
): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32;

// see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873
function CreateProcessWithInheritedHandles(
  lpApplicationName: LPCWSTR;
  lpCommandLine: LPWSTR;
  lpProcessAttributes,
  lpThreadAttributes: PSecurityAttributes;
  const Handles: array of THandle;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: LPCWSTR;
  const lpStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  var lpProcessInformation: TProcessInformation
): Boolean;

const
  PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST = $00020002;

  // this flag is ignored these days, and struct size is used, but we may as well follow the letter of the docs
  EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = $00080000;

type
  TStartupInfoEx = record
    StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
    lpAttributeList: Pointer;
  end;

var
  Handle: THandle;
  StartupInfoEx: TStartupInfoEx;
  size: SIZE_T;

begin
  Assert(Length(Handles)>0);

  StartupInfoEx.StartupInfo := lpStartupInfo;
  StartupInfoEx.StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfoEx);
  StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList := nil;

  Win32Check(not InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(nil, 1, 0, size) and (GetLastError=ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER));
  GetMem(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList, size);
  try
    Win32Check(InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, size));
    try
      Win32Check(UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
        StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList,
        0,
        PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST,
        @Handles[0],
        Length(Handles) * SizeOf(Handles[0]),
        nil,
        nil
      ));

      for Handle in Handles do begin
        Win32Check(SetHandleInformation(Handle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT));
      end;

      Result := CreateProcess(
        lpApplicationName,
        lpCommandLine,
        lpProcessAttributes,
        lpThreadAttributes,
        True,
        dwCreationFlags or EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT,
        lpEnvironment,
        lpCurrentDirectory,
        StartupInfoEx.StartupInfo,
        lpProcessInformation
      );
    finally
      DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(StartupInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
  end;
end;
```

From your post it would seem that there are some declarations of `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList`, `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` and `DeleteProcThreadAttributeList` in the `Windows` unit in the latest versions of Delphi, but your post implies that they are incorrectly declared. The above code is known to work correctly.

**Update**: I've updated the code to include the `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT` process creation flag as suggested by @blerontin. I don't believe that it is necessary because the size of the startup info struct is what the system uses to make that determination. However, the docs say it should be used, and it's harmless to include it.

I've also looked at the declarations of `InitializeProcThreadAttributeList` and `UpdateProcThreadAttribute` in the latest Delphi `Windows` unit in the RTL (version 11.3 as I write) and they are indeed bogus.

Comment: From Microsoft CreateProcess Flags documentation it seems that the `dwCreationFlags` should have EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT flag set. Is this optional or do you add that flag outside of `CreateProcessWithInheritedHandles`?

Comment: @blerontin The docs for `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) say "The process is created with extended startup information; the lpStartupInfo parameter specifies a STARTUPINFOEX structure.
Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: This value is not supported." So I think that the documentation in `CreateProcess` that you refer to is out of date.

Comment: I was looking at the same text but my interpretation seems to be different :) From my tests on Windows 10 at least your answer works correctly when the flag is there.

Comment: @blerontin the flag is simply ignored. The determination of which startup info struct type to use is based on the provided size. MS docs often contain contradictions like this that are of historical nature. The editor updated the flag to note it is no  longer supported. But didn't update other topics that reference it.

Comment: Yes, apparently the flag is ignored. But the documentation does not say "Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP _or later_ not supported". The STARTUPINFOEX structure was only introduced in Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista.

Comment: @blerontin I've updated the code in any case. Thanks for your input!